# Unable to resolve --> ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, asp.net-core-6.0

I have just started working on docker, so please go easy on me.

I have an .NetCore(.Net 6.0) API. I want to integrate prometheus and grafana with this API.

I have followed a YouTube tutorial and created the required .yml files. However when i try to build my docker-compose file i get the below error

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2783899235/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
```

Please help me in finding the issue.

**Dockerfile**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 7068

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Src/PaymentService.Api/PaymentService.Api.csproj", "Src/PaymentService.Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Src/PaymentService.Api/PaymentService.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Src/PaymentService.Api"
RUN dotnet build "PaymentService.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PaymentService.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PaymentService.Api.dll"]
```

**prometheus.yml**

```
global: 
    scrape_interval: 10s
    scrape_timeout: 5s

rule_files:

scrape_configs:
 - job_name: "Prospera.PaymentService"
   static_configs: 
    - targets: ["host.docker.internal:7068"]
```

**dockerfile-prometheus.yml**

```
FROM quay.io/prometheus:latest
ADD prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "7068"
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  paymentservice.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
      - "7068"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro
```

Comment: Which service is producing that error?  Do you get the same error if you remove all of the other services from their `docker-compose.yml` file, and if so, can you [edit] the question to include only the shorter file and omit the unnecessary configuration (reduce the question to a [mcve])?

Comment: Just from the error message, it suggests it's the `web` container and the complaint is that there isn't a `Dockerfile` in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml`.